# PHP Uploader: How to set upload path to local computer?

Tags: php, upload, hosting, local, uploader

How can I set my uploader to save uplodaded files into folder on my computer? I'm hosting a free server on 000webhost.com and I have a simple uploader script ^^
So I'd like to do something like this:

```
//specify folder for file upload
$folder = "C:\Users\Tepa\Desktop\Ohjelmat\Uploads";
```

Comment: so you have a server.... this server is at your home and you want to set up the save path when someone uploads a file ? if yes... just take a look at [move_uploaded_file](http://de1.php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php) keep you eyes on destination!

Comment: If the script is running on a server, how do you expect it to be able to access a directory on your machine at home?

Comment: When you save the file in server-side code, you set its path there.  In what way is this not working?  If you want the server to save a file to the computer running the web browser, it doesn't work that way.  Thankfully, web pages can't access the client's file system.

Comment: Hey guys, I got that it's not possible to move uploads path to local computer. Is there a script which would move them to local computer every 1 hour?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a website save files on your local computer, you will need to install a ftp or other fileserver on your home computer and send the file by IP address, or DNS address.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead to tackle this from the opposite direction and write a script to pull these files to your local computer rather than open it up to the outside world.  You can set it up as either a cron job / scheduled task so that the files are pulled in automatically.

If the files you are interested in are stored in a publicly accessible folder on your host, actually accomplishing this task is fairly trivial (see: [cURL](http://php.net/curl) or [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents))

You loose the real-time synchronicity, but gain some peace of mind.